# Параллельное чтение файлов

Tags: c++, boost

Задача: параллельно читать файлы, выводить в консоль имя файла и цифру из файла, в конце выводить сумму цифр из файлов.

Код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost\filesystem\fstream.hpp>
#include <boost\thread\thread.hpp>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

vector<int> values;
FILE* txt;
fs::path path("c:\\text");

std::vector<boost::thread> threads;

std::mutex m;

int result = 0;

void readFile(fs::directory_iterator it) {
    fs::ifstream ifs(*it);
    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            int val;
            ifs >> val;
            result += val;
            cout << it->path().filename() << ": " << val << endl;
        }
        ifs.close();
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
    }
    else {
        cerr << "Ошибка!" << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Введите путь к файлам (*.txt) (например C:\\text): ";
    cin >> path;
    cout << endl;

    for (fs::directory_iterator it(path); it != fs::directory_iterator(); ++it) {
        if (it->path().extension() == ".txt") {
            threads.push_back(boost::thread(readFile, it));
        }
    }
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
    cout << "Сумма всех чисел: " << result << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В файлах (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt...) числа 1, 10, 100, 1000 и и.д. в конце должно получиться 1111111, но сейчас результат такой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так и как это исправить?

Comment: У вас точно в первых файлах 1, 10 и 100? Вы из проверяли?

Comment: И вынесите `int val;
            ifs >> val;` перед блокировкой мьютекса, иначе у вас и так небольшая параллельность - и та теряется...

Comment: Да, в файлах точные числа.

Comment: И по скрину видно, что некоторые имена дублируются, но значения разные

Comment: Может у ваших файлах разрешение не .txt? А например .TXT?

Comment: Понимаете, ваш boost лично мне поперек... Без него я бы попробовал скомпилировать и проверить на VC++, а так... Тут уж пусть кто-то другой.

Comment: Нет, расширение .txt

Comment: Приложите лог из консоли с вызовом команды dir в директории c:\\text

Comment: Итератор же по ссылке передается? И значение по этой ссылке каждый раз меняется в цикле, нет?

Comment: Кроме того я бы советовал передавать в функцию readFile просто путь к файлу по значению, а не объект directory_iterator

Comment: @Unick я не настолько глуп https://pp.vk.me/c837622/v837622894/21793/E78WYH6yg2k.jpg

Comment: @Unick как это правильно записать?

Comment: Судя по выводу так и есть вы читаете 3.txt 3 раза, т.к. итератор успевает измениться в гавном потоке и потоки 1, 2, 3 используют одно и тоже значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему проблема гонки между главным поток и потоками для чтения файлов. Объект fs::directory_iterator it успевает поменяться, пока потоки 1, 2 начнут работать. Следовательно стоит передавать путь в функции потоков по значению. Код будет выглядить примерно так:

```
....
void readFile(fs::path filePath) {
....
}
...
if (it->path().extension() == ".txt") {
   threads.push_back(boost::thread(readFile, it->path()));
}
```